# Extracting a column from a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pivot

I started with this dataframe

```
life_expectancy.head(5)
    

|   |   Entity    | Code | Year | Life expectancy |

| 0 | Afghanistan | AFG  | 1950 |          27.638 |

| 1 | Afghanistan | AFG  | 1951 |          27.878 |

| 2 | Afghanistan | AFG  | 1952 |          28.361 |

| 3 | Afghanistan | AFG  | 1953 |          28.852 |

| 4 | Afghanistan | AFG  | 1954 |          29.350 |
```

I have created the following pivot table from an existing df

```
pivot = life_expectancy.pivot_table('Life expectancy', index=['Entity'], columns = ['Year'])
```

I am trying to access the Year 2019, but have no success

```
pivot['Year']['2019']
```

Comment: _I am trying to access the Year 2019, but have no success_ What does that mean, specifically? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `'Year'`, try `pivot[2019]` (or if values in the `'Year'` column are strings, not integers, use `pivot['2019']`).

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is for accessing the column is wrong. Here is the correct way:

```
#converts columns names into strings
pivot.columns = map(str, pivot.columns)

#acessing the column '2019'
pivot['2019']
```

**Output on the test data**:

```
>>> pivot.columns = map(str, pivot.columns)
>>> pivot['1950']
Entity
 Afghanistan     27.638
Name: 1950, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know it works for you. If it does please consider accepting/check-marking (✓) the answer.